# What is the correct way to incorporate sampling weights into a spatial regression?

Tags: r, regression, spatial, sample-weighting

I want to know what the proper procedure is for incorporating sampling weights into a regression. I am running a spatial regression using survey data in R. I'm using the function `lagsarlm()` in the `spatialreg` package. I'm just unsure of how to incorporate sampling weights, or whether it's even appropriate to do so. I notice that `lm()` (and I think `errorsarlm()`) take the square root of the weights vector and multiply $x$ and $y$ by that.

Would this be appropriate here? Or are there major theoretical problems that would impact inference? I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work, but notice that these functions do not support sampling weights using what I would assume are readily available methods.